Can't get modifiers
I cant find the wrench for the Modifiers tab, I just started and it was never shown for me in the first place.
I am using blender 4.3 in which I downloaded from the Microsoft Store.
I have looked thoroughly online and cannot find an explanation for as to why the wrench is not there, I am attempting to follow a Blender guide to use materials yet as it is not there.


I have a simple test for you. Star blender with the default scene, select the default cube and check if there is a wrench tab. Bet you there will be one

As far as I am aware, you cannot use modifiers on Metaballs, I would recommend converting the metaball object to a mesh first. To do so, select the "Object" dropdown menu from the top right, next to the button that lets you switch from object mode to edit mode, then go down to "Convert" and select "Convert to mesh"

Thanks guys!! I followed both and they worked well, I really appreciate you responding to help! The hand grenade is one step closer to looking correct

Do modifiers really apply to "MBall" elements? (I don't even know what these are)

@DanielMöller No, you cannot add modifiers to Metaball objects as Nascent Space already commented, and that's what an "MBall" is.
